# ("/^[a-zA-Z\_\- ]*$/") in angular not working for input box. I only need to input character not number but this didn't work.it can also accept number

Tags: angular

username: ['', Validators.required,Validators.pattern("^[a-zA-Z]+([ -][a-zA-Z]+)*$")],

not working in angular

Comment: Please add some code and some clarity.

Answer (score 1):

If multiple validations need to be added, then it should be passed as an array. Try to correct the syntax for the form validation as follows,

From this

```
username: ['', Validators.required,Validators.pattern("^[a-zA-Z]+([ -][a-zA-Z]+)*$")],
```

To

```
 username: ['', [Validators.required,Validators.pattern("^[a-zA-Z]+([ -][a-zA-Z]+)*$")]],
```

Comment: username: ['', [Validators.required,Validators.pattern("^[a-zA-Z ]*")]] this code is also run without an error